# How to check if map array value is getting repeated with different key in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, hashmap, iterator

I have a Map having "String" as a key and "Array" as value.
now my problem is how am I supposed to check if the array item is present in different "Array" value? i.e. "Array" of the different key in the map.

For Ex:

```
var map = {
"KeyA" : [123,111,100],
"KeyB" : [147,123,789]
}
```

how can I check that array item 123 is present with two different key i.e. KeyA and Key B

Thanks,
Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a generic method and check value in arrays using `every()`:

```js
let map = {
  "KeyA" : [123,111,100],
  "KeyB" : [147,123,789],
  "KeyC" : [147,148,789]
};

let checker = (obj, keys, val) => {
  return keys.every(k => obj[k].includes(val));
}

console.log(checker(map, ["KeyA", "KeyB"], 123));
```

In case you wants to pass an array of values:

```js
let map = {
  "KeyA" : [123,111,100],
  "KeyB" : [147,123,789,111],
  "KeyC" : [147,148,789]
};

let checker = (obj, keys, val) => {
  return keys.every(k => val.every(v => obj[k].includes(v)));
}

console.log(checker(map, ["KeyA", "KeyB"], [123, 111]));
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad,
I can pass array of keys in second argument of checker method but can I pass the value array in 3rd Argument.

means the map which you mentioned has unique value array of [123,111,147,148,789,100].

So if I pass this array as a third argument then can I check that 123 or 147 or 789 is present inside the map with different keys

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this using **Object.keys()** and **.filter**, then we return the keys if the value is present in that array.

I have opted to use **indexOf()** instead of **includes()** as it is not supported in Internet Explorer without a polyfil.

```
const map = {
    "KeyA" : [123,111,100],
    "KeyB" : [147,123,789]
}

function checkForValue(array, value) {
    return Object.keys(array)
        .filter(key => (array[key].indexOf(value) !== -1) ? key : null);  
}

console.log(checkForValue(map, 123)); // [ 'KeyA', 'KeyB']
```